# Get object handler user clicked in scene

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qlist, qvariant

`QList<QWidget *> list;`
In scene user can add no of objects and m storing objects in list. i want to get the object the user clicked or focused one so that i can change properties or delete object. how to get clicked object pointer from list ?

Answer (score 0):

`QWidget` might not have the signals and methods you need to implement this easily.

Look here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/widget-classes.html to find the widget best suited for your needs.

In order to keep track for the signals and to which button they belong you can want  use a `QSignalMapper`.

Comment: sorry i think you didnt understand the question. i have stored object pointers in QList<QWidget *> list; in this list i have to find user clicked object pointer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. If it's already in a list then you can just write list[index] and as I said you can use QSignalMapper to get the index.

Comment: Thanks ... i got some ideas ...i wil try